# Help-me, please! Solve $\oint_{c} xy ds$ where $C$ is the intersection of the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$ and $ y+z=8 $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Solve $\oint_{c} xy ds$ where $C$ is the intersection of the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$ and $ y+z=8 $

Hi. I tried to resolve the issue below using the definition of line integral, but I couldn’t solve it. Could someone appreciate my resolution and help me finish it? Below follows what I did:

$$\oint_{c} xy ds = {\int }_{C}f\left(x,y,z\right)ds= \int_{a}^{b}f\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)\sqrt{{\left({x}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({y}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({z}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}}dt.$$

\begin{align*}
  x&=2\cos t \\
  y&=2\sin t \\
  z&=8-2\sin t
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)&=\langle 2\cos t, 2\sin t, 8-2\sin t \rangle \\
ds = \left\Vert\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)^{\prime} \right\Vert&= \sqrt{{\left({x}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({y}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({z}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}}dt
\end{align*}

Thus,

\begin{align*}
\oint_{c} xy ds ={\int }_{C}f\left(x,y,z\right)ds&={\int_{0}^{2\pi}}(4\cos t\sin t)\sqrt{{\left({-2\sin t}\right)}^{2}+{\left({2\cos t}\right)}^{2}+{\left({-2\cos t}\right)}^{2}} dt \\
  &={\int_0^{2\pi}} 8\cos \left(t\right)\sin \left(t\right)\sqrt{-\sin ^2\left(t\right)+2} dt \\
  &= -\left[\frac{8}{3}\left(1+\cos ^2\left(t \right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{_{0}}^{^{2\pi}} \\
  &=0.
\end{align*}

Thanks!

Comment: Your solutions seems correct. What is the actual answer (assuming you are aware of it) ?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez the answer is $16\pi^2\sqrt(2)$

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is an odd function of $x$ and the curve is invariant under the reflection $x\leftrightarrow -x$ thus

$$I = \oint_Cxy\:ds = \oint_C (-x)y\:ds = -I \implies I=0$$

by odd symmetry.